# How to get clickable links to errors and code lines in CLion terminal (like VS code)

Tags: powershell, terminal, console, ide, clion

Is it possible to to get clickable links to errors and code lines in the CLion terminal? I want to get the same output as the "Build Output", but in the terminal so I can use other commands.

Build output:
[image]

Console output:
[image]

VS code for reference: (using ctrl + click to go to the line of code)

[image]

Note: Using Powershell

Comment: Unfortunately, file links with lines are not yet supported in IntelliJ platform https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221519